# Do pseudo 2-limits commute?

Tags: ct.category-theory, limits-and-colimits, 2-categories

It is a well-known fact that if $F:\mathcal{C}_1\times\mathcal{C}_2\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ is a functor (between 1-categories), then $F$ has a limit if and only if $F:\mathcal{C}_1\rightarrow Fun(\mathcal{C}_2,\mathcal{D})$ has a limit $\lim_{\mathcal{C}_1} F$, and the functor $\lim_{\mathcal{C}_1} F:\mathcal{C}_2\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ has limit. In which case, $$\lim_{\mathcal{C}_1\times\mathcal{C}_2} F = \lim_{\mathcal{C}_2}\lim_{\mathcal{C}_1} F.$$

I expect that a 2-categorical analogue of this statement holds, but I haven't been able to locate it in the literature! More precisely, I'm interested in a version of this result that applies to (weighted) pseudo 2-limits.